# Django html Check form type

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to build an html page in Django, where depending on the form passed the page will render different things. How can I know in the HTML the type of form passed?

I want to do something like this:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section container" >

            {% if form.type == 'ModelAForm' %}
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        {{ form.driver_color }}

                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            {% if form.type == 'ModelBForm' %}
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        {{ form.driver_name}}

                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

On the `{% if form.type == 'ModelAForm' %}` how can I know the form type?

Comment: `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{form.type}}" />`

Comment: Hi! Can you please expand on this?

Comment: I do not know Django - this is what I would do if there is no other way

Comment: Why are you passing the same context variable for different forms? Just pass a different context variable instead of `form` for instance `abc_form` and `def_form`.

Comment: But how do I know which one did I pass? How do I check if its `abc_form` or `def_form`?